# Partitioning in Kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes

I'd like to implement an application for transformation of some data in Kubernetes. The application contains a chain of logical operators.

A --- records R1 ---> B --- records R2 ---> C

- The operator "A" generates records "R1" and passes them to the
  operator "B" (it's not important how the operator generates the
  records).
- The operator "B" transforms the input records "R1" to the output
  records"R2" and passes them to the operator "C" in the push mode.
- The operator "C" processes the records "R2" (it's not important how
  the operator works).

If my transformation is simple I can create the containers "A", "B", and "C" for the operators and put the containers into a pod. I can use the pod as a logical unit to start and stop my application.

But if the cost of my transformation is high I need to scale my application. I'd like to increase the number of instances of the operator "B" and run the transformations in parallel. I'd like to distribute the instances of the operator "B" to several Kubernetes nodes and support the failover for them.

Also I'd like to have a good interface in order to start and stop my application as a regular service.

Can I implement such kind of the application in Kubernetes?

Answer (score 1):

That really depends on how you pass data between services. Are they pushing data up or pulling? Or do they store to some persistent storage? How many requests/records are passing the system and what is their size?

All in all, IMO you should implement each service (A/B/C) as a separate Pod/Deployment. Then you can have services defined for them to be able to call and pull or push data if it's an API based flow. On the other hand you might implement some kind of queue (ie. Kafka or RabbitMQ) and pass messages or just a database where you'd store the records in appropriate tables.

Hard to give a more precise answer without better understanding of the final objective.

Comment: for a high volume solution I would suggest : A(1..n) -push-> Kafka Qb -pull-> B(1..n) -push-> Kafka Qc -pull-> C(1..n) This way you use message passing (as long as your objects/records fit in messages) and whole system is scaling very well on every step

Comment: @radek-goblin-pieczonka I understand I can use Kafka for implementation of the application. But my question is about Kubernetes. Does it contain the infrastructure to make an application that can distribute containers between the Kubernetes nodes and to allow to manage by the application as a single service?

Comment: The key here is "manage" and what do you mean by that. If you just want to have say `A(1..n) --http-push--> B(1..n) --http-push--> C(1..n)` then sure, just define appropriate services and kube will loadbalance between multiple pods. That is what services are for. Want to scale them dynamicaly based on ie. CPU use, sure kube HPA supports that. Want to have advanced work scheduling with pickup queue/confirmations/retries etc. you should probably use kube features AND message queue

Comment: @radek-goblin-pieczonka Thank you very much!